# Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a reconstruction matrix (A) for a image with shape (7500, 81920) and I am getting the error that it is bigger than 2GB. The line where I get the error is the one in which I calculate "our_loss". Does anyone know how I can still use a matrix this large in my program?

```
    A = np.random.randn(7500, 81920).astype('float32')

    y = np.dot(A, v) 
    y_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,m])
    our_loss = tf.reduce_mean( tf.reduce_sum( (tf.matmul(tf.reshape(G[0], [1, -1]) , A.T) - y_placeholder)**2, 1)) 

    z_optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(our_loss, var_list=z)  
    for i in range(num_iter): 
        a, closs, b = sess.run([z_optim, our_loss, G],feed_dict={y_placeholder: y})
```